# How to utilize unique_test_names when importing subflows with the same test name?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am trying to run multiple flows at once by creating a master flow file and importing all my flows as subflows as shown below.

```
Flow.create(interface: 'MyTest::Interface', test_module: :shell) do
import 'openshort_ft_flow.rb', dir:"/users/rkoripal/program", test_module:'openshort'.to_sym
```

When doing this I have a few test names that are repeated because we have multiple flow files with common content, and I am getting the error “Cannot create test, it already exists!”

I tried setting the unique_test_names option to true when importing as shown below.

```
def import(sub_flow, options = {})
  options= {
    test_module: current_test_module_obj.nil? ? sub_flow.split('_')[0].to_sym : current_test_module_obj.name,
    dir: "../../#{options[:test_module]}/origen"
  }.update(options)
  @current_test_module_obj = Origen.top_level.test_modules(options[:test_module])
  sub_flow = "#{options[:dir]}/#{sub_flow}"
  options[:unique_test_names] = true
  super(sub_flow, options)
end
```

How can I import the subflows with unique test names to avoid getting this error?

Comment: I don't recognize that error message or the code snippet you show as part of Origen. Is this error originating from somewhere within your application space?